# Can DB2 Sequences be replicated in Q replication

Tags: db2, aix

We have a requirement to determine the last Assigned value of a DB2 sequence.The sequence is used by multiple tables & we can't replicate all of them.
I can get these values from sysibm.syssequences, however replicating this table is not allowed in any OS except z/os (we have AIX 6.1).
Is there any way that I can replicate a Db2 sequence?

Comment: Can you elaborate what it is you are trying to accomplish, what the goal is?

Comment: We are using Q replication to replicate data from Source to target DB. sone of the audit tables in Source DB are using DB2 sequences,we can't replicate data from these tables. The Goal is to determine the last Assigned value of a DB2 sequence they were using. One way of doing it is what I've mentioned (replicate sysibm.syssequences) the other may be to replicate the DB2 Sequence if at all possible. If not, is there any way it can be achieved?? Thanks.